# React setState does not change the state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to change the value of a TreeSelect component from the antd (antdesign) UI library. I think I did everything the way they describe in [their help](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001), the only difference is that I'm using Typescript.

> I can't change the state of `treeSelection` in the `onChange` function. The value is always `undefined`.

Here's the `TreeBrowser` I built, and I'm simply using it in another file as . Note that all the other components where I import TreeBrowser work perfectly.

**TreeBrowser.tsx**:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TreeSelect } from "antd";

const treeData = [{
  label: 'Node1',
  value: '0-0',
  key: '0-0',
  children: [{
    label: 'Child Node1',
    value: '0-0-1',
    key: '0-0-1',
  }, {
    label: 'Child Node2',
    value: '0-0-2',
    key: '0-0-2',
  }],
}, {
  label: 'Node2',
  value: '0-1',
  key: '0-1',
}];

export interface TreeBrowserProps {};
export interface TreeBrowserState {
  treeSelection: string;
};

export class TreeBrowser extends React.Component<TreeBrowserProps, TreeBrowserState> {

  state = {
    treeSelection: undefined 
  }

  onChange = (treeSelection: string) => {
    console.log(treeSelection);  // This prints correctly the treeSelection  
    this.setState({treeSelection}, () => {
      console.log('Im never called :(');
      console.log(this.state.treeSelection); // console.log is never called
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TreeSelect
        style={{ width: 300 }}
        value={this.state.treeSelection}
        dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto' }}
        treeData={treeData}

        treeDefaultExpandAll
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true    
  },
  "lib": [
    "es6",
    "dom"
  ],
  "types": [
    "webpack-env",
    "aspnet-webpack-react"
  ],
  "paths": {
    // Fix "Duplicate identifier" errors caused by multiple dependencies fetching their own copies of type definitions.
    // We tell TypeScript which type definitions module to treat as the canonical one (instead of combining all of them).
    "history": [
      "./node_modules/@types/history/index"
    ],
    "redux": [
      "./node_modules/@types/redux/index"
    ],
    "react": [
      "./node_modules/@types/react/index"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules"
  ]

}
```

Comment: because of `setState` is async?

Comment: I thought at first, but why would it work in the CodePen demo then?

Comment: Have you heard about second parameter for `setState`? It's a callback which is fired right after when states have been updated. So put your `console.log` there. Your CodePen is empty :(

Comment: I updated my code with your suggestion. Now, the `console.log` function with the callback is never called

Comment: It is called , but as there is context issue , it must be throwing error. Try writing callback as arrow function and then it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what was wrong. I had originally initiated the `treeSelection` value to `undefined`, while the type is `string`. I changed it to a valid value `0-0` and this did the trick. Could also have done `treeSelection: ''`

```
export interface TreeBrowserProps {};
export interface TreeBrowserState {
  treeSelection: string;
};

export class TreeBrowser extends React.Component<TreeBrowserProps, TreeBrowserState> {

  state = {
    treeSelection: '0-0'
  }

  onChange = (treeSelection: string) => {    
    this.setState({treeSelection});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TreeSelect
        style={{ width: 300 }}

        dropdownStyle={{ maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto' }}
        treeData={treeData}
        value={this.state.treeSelection}
        treeDefaultExpandAll        
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange = (treeSelection: string) => {
    console.log(treeSelection);  // This prints correctly the treeSelection  
    this.setState({treeSelection}, () => {
      console.log(this.state.treeSelection); // console.log is never called
    });
  }
This should print properly. So bacically when you used non arroe function
syntax, you are loosing the context. arrow functions persist the context from the outer scope. read more about arrow functions here
```

[arrow-functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Hi, I think you should explain what's different and how that change works

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does nothing. I am starting to wonder if this is related to a tsconfig issue, or something else. I updated my code in the question